# Hacer post de php a servicio rest c#

Tags: php, javascript, c#, webservice, rest

Buenas tardes, ojalá que alguien pueda orientarme.

Estoy realizando una integración de pagos.
Para la aplicación estoy usando angular y javascript.
En cuanto a mis servicios, uso rest c#, reciben json.
La página externa de la que no tengo control, emplea php.

Desde mi página hago un submit(a) a una página externa en la que lleno
los datos como número de tarjeta, código de seguridad, etc. Cuando
termino, hago clic en pagar y a su vez, esa página verifica los datos
de la tarjeta y en teoría, debería redireccionarme a mi página, indicando
si se aceptó el pago o no (enviándome parámetros de transacción).

El submit del que hablé anteriormente usa un form con post, en el que envió un "MerchantResponseURL" (Webhook a donde se reportaran los parámetros de la transacción).

Cuando comienza el redireccionamiento a mi página, se hace un post de php a mi MerchantResponseURL (que actualmente es un servicio web rest en c#). Ese post del que yo
no tengo control, se hace también con un submit como el de este link: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit.
El problema, es que cuando yo recibo el post, el servicio web no puede aceptar el tipo de datos que vienen en ese post. He solicitado que el post que recibo tengo un content type json, pero se niegan a incluirlo.
¿Qué podría hacer al respecto?

Gracias por su atención, ojalá puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Tienes que configurar los tipos de datos que puedes recibir en tu servicio, para el caso que estas confrontando el header que debes validar que puedas recibir es application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Gracias Lcop, he intentado cambiar el requestFormat en mi servicio, pero solo me muestra las opciones de json y xml, he buscado al respecto anteriormente y no he tenido éxito, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Podrías poner mas información?.. en que formato es el que te estan mandando los datos.. y en como tienes tu metodo en el api?.. si te lo esta mandando por `form` en el body puedes tratar var something= httpContext.Request.Form["nombre de la variable"];

Answer (score 0):

Una web api no tiene problemas para trabajar con un formulario, la prueba que realice fue la siguiente:

Formulario html:

```
<form action="/api/MerchantResponseURL" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Al hacer submit el post que realiza es similar a:**

> POST http://localhost:61789/api/MerchantResponseURL HTTP/1.1
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
>   Referer:
>   https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language:
>   es,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4 Cookie:
>   __gads=ID=5c38ba44426c9aeb:T=1479934000:S=ALNI_MYIippZvxSX1zRedEMC9x4aRPxJMA;
>   ezouid_34890=1263373480; __qca=P0-402894760-1491317446847;
>   ezosuigeneris=2c5eceef407b0d5880b5a3aa6656efb0;
>   __utma=119627022.1866741841.1421853006.1492528048.1492817010.14; __utmz=119627022.1492817010.14.13.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided);
>   _ga=GA1.2.1866741841.1421853006 Host: localhost:61789 Content-Length: 31
>
> firstname=Mickey&lastname=Mouse

y la definición del controlador de la API es:

```
public class MerchantResponseURLController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Elemento x)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = 
        Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        return response;
    }

}
```

La clase elemento:

```
public class Elemento
{
    public string firstname { set; get; }
    public string lastname { set; get; }

}
```